# funny behaviour or what - dc motor control

Tags: motor

I'm trying to control the speed of this [motor](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1117), with this [motor driver](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/2130) and pic16f690.

pwm in my program

```
5 kHz frequency (0.2 ms period)
```

Starting with 50% duty cycle the motor doesn't run.
But moving from say, 80% to 50% (i.e. program my PIC with 80% duty cycle, and then re-program it with 50%), the motor will run at 50% (of course at a lower speed). I consider this funny. Anyone to explain this?

my motor powered by 5V.

Answer (score 5):

If you're saying that it always starts with 80% PWM, but never with 50%, but it runs with 50% after starting, then you're just starting to learn the joys of working with a system that has significant stiction (AKA starting friction).

Somewhere buried in this document is a description, along with some prescriptions of how to deal with it in a closed-loop control system: 
http://wescottdesign.com/articles/Friction/friction.pdf

Comment: yeah! that's what I mean. thanks for the document.